# how can I get a filename of images using muter upload.fields

Tags: node.js, express, multer

please help me out, I want to save the filename of the image in the database.

how can I get the filename of the image using multer `upload.fields`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the object req.files and then again the result e get the filenames.

```
req.files.forEach(file => {
  file.forEach(item => {
    console.log("Filename", item.filename)
  })
})
```

You can save it directly or append it to a list and then save them.